# Magento 2 addProductsFilter to Stock Item collection

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

In Magento 1 you were able to add a product filter to a Stock Item collection in the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item_Collection` class. This functionality appears to be missing along with the other methods included in the Magento 1 class.

Additionally, it appears that you cannot addFieldToFilter to a Stock Item collection due to the models that it extends (i.e.

`Magento\Framework\Data\AbstractSearchResult`

is extended as opposed to something like the Product Collection of which extends:

`Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`)

So my question is, **how are you supposed to add a product filter to a stock item collection on Magento 2** (And indeed if it's possible).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm typing down same question, do you have any way by now?